# ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY

Tags: objective-c

I found one solution related with `Addresponse - adding to memory only` on Stackoverflow, but my App still reporting it even doing the recommended.

[Addresponse - adding to memory only (XCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579748/addresponse-adding-to-memory-only-xcode)

---

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    ...
    // Enable Cache System
    NSURLCache *cache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4*1024*1024 diskCapacity:32*1024*1024 diskPath:nil];
    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
    ...
}
```

Log:

```
2013-05-22 19:44:21.648 Setparty[12912:380f] ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: http://SERVER/api/1.0/appimages/?view=1
2013-05-22 19:44:21.667 Setparty[12912:380f] ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: http://SERVER/api/1.0/appimages/?view=2
2013-05-22 19:44:21.689 Setparty[12912:380f] ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: http://itunes.apple.com/lookup/?id=634476579
```

---

Does anyone have any idea what may be related with these logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an error message coming from the framework.  Best guess, your path on disk is `nil` and, thus, that error message is telling you that nothing will be written to disk.

Comment: I'll test on my App if `diskPath` is set it fix the problem, but I guess it do not have any relation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300044/on-ios-where-is-the-nsurlcache-cache-stored-if-diskpathnil?lq=1

Comment: UPDATE: Even with `diskPath` set it still reporting `ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY`.

Comment: What did you set the disk path to?  Somewhere writable?

Comment: I saw this when using `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:(NSUInteger)length encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding` … Length was `length:outputLength` when it should have been `length:&outputLength` So, another possible clue for future readers.