# ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY: - is this bad?

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Only recently am i seeing `ADDRESPONSE - ADDING TO MEMORY ONLY:` in my log. Is this something to be concerned about (future crash) or is it ok?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547490/log-messages-i-didnt-asked-for-in-xcode-4-5-with-ios-6-0

Comment: One comment claims that this is ok, is your feeling metual? But everyone else seemed concerned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703059/addresponse-adding-to-memory-only).

It says if you are not giving correct path while writing any file or something like this. This error might occur.

If you are not doing any such thing in your app. It should be ok to ignore this warning.

Comment: my app is reading from a link not writing to it

Comment: I guess this is not error or warning, but simply a notification. If you want to get rid of this log message, you can try to clear your cookies and data in the safari settings.

Comment: Thanks, it only happens every now and again